# How to add the ngModelChange in div with some functionality

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown, ngfor

I have an angular applicaion in that I have nz-select to show the drop down and I have ngModelcange and ngModel in that .

**.component.ts**

```
<nz-select nzode="default" [nzShowSearch]="true" [nzOnSearch] ="searchusers($event)"
[nzPlaceholder]="Searc" [nzFilterOption]="nzFilterOption"
(ngModelChange)="OnSelected($event)"
[(ngModel)]="listOfUserSelect">
<nz-option *ngFor ="let option of userslist" [nzLabel]="option.label" [nzValue]="option.value">
</nz-option>
</nz-select>
```

My requirement is to show the above nz-select dropdown in  divs

```
<div ngFor "let option of userslist" >
<div class="optionlist" >
<div style ="width:200px;">{{option.label}}</div>
</div>
```

Now I am able to  iterate in each divs but I am unable to do the onchange funtionality as in above dropdown

So as in above dropdown I need to add the same funtionalities like ngOnchange etc

Can anyone help me on this

Comment: Why do you want to do it using `DIV`s?

Comment: Because I need to add some styles which I am unable to equal to mockup if I use dropdown, can you help me on this